# 404 Not Found with Apache server

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404

I am trying to get my website setup and whenever I try to use my domain name to connect I get "404 Not Found"

When I try and reach the site with my IP it works fine.

I am on Debian x64.

Can someone please help me get this resolved.

If you need more information just ask.

[Httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/2KEszZ0U)

[Apache2.conf](http://pastebin.com/px5vDw84)

Comment: @Arnestig: You don't know if the problem actually is debian specific or not.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: Well we don't know if this problem is caused by a hardware issue, software issue or some other problem. It's good that Nicholas Brown informs us that he's running on Debian x64, but the question itself is not related to Debian. He's not asking a question regarding how Debian works / behaves etc. This question is entirely directed at getting apache up and running. Therefore the tag "apache".

Answer (score 2):

Where do you have your website ? On local network or on a hosting service provider?

In any case you need to add your web-server ip to the DNS server (either local or www) depending upon your requirements, without knowing where your webserver is local or global it is difficult to give you an answer

Comment: Good point. I didn't even consider the DNS settings, but that should be looked at as well.

Comment: My site is on a providers VPS.

Comment: @Nicholas Brown That doesn't necessarily mean the DNS settings are correct.

Comment: How do I check the DNS settings?

Comment: Oky, If you have access to your Domain Management Console, You need to create 'A' Record for your domain to point to your server, 'C' Record for subdomains, 'MX' Record for Email server, 

Check the documentation of your VPS Service Provider and also your Domain Management Console, they will have good documentation on pointing your domain to your web-server,

Comment: How would I go about creating 'A' record? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Can you let me know the VPS Provider and Domain Provider so that i can point you to the exact documentations ? Because it is easy to learn from Documentation

Comment: For Example I have my servers with Amazon or RackSpace and My Domain name with BigRock or Godaddy etc ..,

Comment: This the only resources I can find on the link you provided., man they dont have any documentation probably a very new service provider.,

http://forum.fluctis.com/showthread.php?tid=46&highlight=domain

Rackspace Documentation on How to create A records etc .., 

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/dns-creating-a-dns-record-for-cloud-servers

Im assuming you have a dedicated public ip address and not a shared one .,

Comment: That;s what I was thinking, very limited documentation. Yes it is dedicated.

Comment: I suggest you make a new ticket and ask them to point you towards the resources .., If you can manage to fine the DNS Setting in your Control Panel you can absolutely follow the Rackspace Documentation to Create the Records., Because it is the same for any Domain DNS Management

Comment: @NicholasBrown I was in the same situation when i started out, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Virtual host should look like this:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin nicholas_brown@rocketmail.com
        DocumentRoot /home/web/websites/special-faces.net
        ServerName special-faces.net
        ServerAlias www.special-faces.net
        ErrorLog /home/web/website_logs/errorlog.txt
        CustomLog /home/web/website_logs/accesslog.txt common

        <Directory "/home/web/websites/special-faces.net">
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

     </VirtualHost>
```

If you want to use .htaccess files, add this after the "Allow from all" line:

```
    Allowoverride all
```

Comment: @Nicholas Brown Have you looked into the DNS settings?

Answer (score 0):

For Server version: Apache/2.4.16 and later,

```
<VirtualHost localhost.com:80>
        ServerName localhost.com
        ServerAlias localhost.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        RewriteEngine On

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        DocumentRoot /home/<user name where code will be placed>/public_html/html
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combinedtimezone

</VirtualHost>
```